# Elixir - Get Host By Name?

Tags: elixir

How do you gethostbyname with Elixir?

There doesn't seem to be a supported API and the two solutions seem to revolve around,

1. Erlang's Inet
2. Fork to shell with System (`hostname`)

Comment: are you looking for a native solution, or simply how to use inet from Elixir? the `inet` module works great

Comment: Native? I am assuming now that there isn't one by the responses....or lack thereof.

Comment: By native, I meant an Elixir module, rather than an Erlang one. But you can use Erlang modules in Elixir: `:inet.gethostbyname('google.com')`

Comment: The inet one is definitely the way to go!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The general philosophy in Elixir is that if a solution exists in standard erlang libraries, there is no reason to simply reproduce that solution with a elixir wrapper unless you are going to provide added functionality in some way.

Or in other words, erlang libraries are native.

```
iex(2)> :inet.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
{:ok, {:hostent, 'www.google.com', [], :inet, 4, [{216, 58, 192, 4}]}}
```

Note: the single quotes above are important, you can convert an Elixir string
to an Erlang one by using String.to_charlist

```
iex(5)> :inet.gethostbyname(String.to_char_list("www.google.com"))
{:ok, {:hostent, 'www.google.com', [], :inet, 4, [{216, 58, 192, 4}]}}
```